# autocliclear el boton Start your 30-day free trial de amazon.com

Tags: html

Quiero crear una cuenta Amazon prime automáticamente

Con visual creé el proyecto y actualmente, solo falta hacer click automáticamente en el botón **Start your 30-days free trial**.

No puedo hacerlo mediante el DOM de la página porque el botón, aparentemente, no tiene ninguna clase ni id asociada.

`<input class="a-button-input" type="submit" aria-labelledby="a-autoid-0-announce">`

Dejo una imagen para que me entiendan mejor:

[image: Dejo una imagen para que me entiendan mejor]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: Te puedo ayudar fácilmente, pero no se en qué lenguaje lo estás haciendo, ni la forma de hacerlo, si pones parte de tu código, te puedo resolver el problema.

Comment: Mira lo estoy haciendo desde visual estudio y la unica idea que tengo para darle click es con esta line de codigo, pero tampoco he podido              For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
            If element.GetAttribute("value") = "a-autoid-0-announce" Then
                element.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next

Answer (score 1):

Como no dices el lenguaje en el que lo realizas, te lo digo en pseudocódigo:

1. Obtienes todos los elementos cuya clase sea `a-button-input`
2. Filtras esos elementos cuyo contenido sea: `Start your 30-day free trial`
3. Llamas al método .click() de ese elemento